# How to get linetype and color in same the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line, legend

I cannot seem to get the linetype and color to display in the same legend, it will display two legends; one with lines and one with the colors. what am I missing?

```
Data_basinflow_pivot %>%
  filter(name == c("baseline", "baseline", "t6_p130", "t6_p130"))%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = julian, y = value, color = name, linetype = name))+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = julian, y = value, color = name, linetype = name ))+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = julian, y = value, color = name, linetype = name))+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = julian, y = value, color = name, linetype = name))+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("baseline", "baseline", "t6_p130", "t6_p130"),
                     values = c("blue","blue","black","black"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("baseline", "baseline", "t6_p130", "t6_p130"),
  values=c("dashed", "solid", "dashed", "solid"))+
  labs(y = "", color = "Class", x = "Julian Day")+
  ylim(0,0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `labs(y = "", color = "Class", x = "Julian Day", linetype = "Class")`.

Comment: Yes wow thank youuuu!